# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ddBarChart is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Working on MVC 5 project. This particular page is a partial page (Razor), if that makes any difference.

I'm trying to utilize a ddchart jQuery library. (http://kiersimmons.com/ddchart/index.html) I keep getting this error...

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ddBarChart is not a function
```

The line of code that the error is happening on is here:

```
$("#chart_div_static").ddBarChart({
        chartDataLink: "~/Scripts/plugins/ddchart/Chart_Data.js?1=10",
        action: 'init',
        xOddClass: "ui-state-active",
        xEvenClass: "ui-state-default",
        yOddClass: "ui-state-active",
        yEvenClass: "ui-state-default",
        xWrapperClass: "ui-widget-content",
        chartWrapperClass: "ui-widget-content",
        chartBarClass: "ui-state-focus ui-corner-top",
        chartBarHoverClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        callBeforeLoad: function () { $('#loading-Notification_static').fadeIn(0); },
        callAfterLoad: function () { $('#loading-Notification_static').stop().fadeOut(0); },
        tooltipSettings: { extraClass: "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" }
    });
```

I know the function exists and the reference (to the js file that contains the function) is placed before ddBarChart is called. FYI the reference is....

```
<script src="~/Scripts/plugins/ddchart/jquery.ddchart.js"></script>
```

As a test: In my jquery.ddchart.js file I even made a test() function that simply pops up an alert. I wrote this function on the line before the ddBarChart function. When I call the test function it works fine. So I know the reference to the external js file (jquery.ddchart.js) is correct.

**** Update ****

FYI: The ddBarChart function, in the external file, starts off as...

```
jQuery.fn.ddBarChart = function(options) {
        function setupDrillDown(strID, intDelay, strH, strW, strL) {
            $(strID+ "> .ddchart-chart-final").css("z-index","2");
               :
               :
        }

        function aniDrillDown(strID,intDelay) {
            $(strID+ " > .ddchart-chart-final > .ddchart-chart-wrapper-sub").animate( {width: "100%",height: "100%",left: "0%"}, intDelay-500, function(){aniCleanUp(strID)});  
        }
               :
               :
```

**** Update Note ****
(This is a MVC 5 partial page (razor), if that makes any difference. Seemed to work when I created a normal non-partial page in a different project.)

Any ideas what this could be? Thanks!

Comment: Is this inside a `$(document).ready()`? And if so could you try using `$(window).on("load", function() {});` instead?

Comment: Thanks for your response @TylerRoper ... It is not within a $(document).ready()

Comment: I did try changing to put the code in document.ready but that didn't work either. What's weird is that my test function (with a simple alert) worked perfectly fine! It's in the same location. (Also, this is a MVC 5 partial page (razor), if that makes any difference. Seemed to work when I created a normal non-partial page in a different project.)

Comment: Try including it with `<script src="@Href("~/Scripts/plugins/ddchart/jquery.ddchart.js")"></script>`

Comment: Thanks @AndrewShepherd .... But, I know the reference is working because of my test. The test function (alert) was in the exact same file.

Comment: @WebDevGuy2 In what block are you doing `$("#chart_div_static").ddBarChart({`? Perhaps it's attempting to run prior to the inclusion of the file? If you run an alert in the first line of your included JS, and also just above `$("#chart_div_static").ddBarChart({`, which alert fires first?

Comment: @TylerRoper I definitely include the file before calling ddBarChart. As mentioned, above the actual ddBarChart function I created a simple test function that shows an alert. From the main page I tried calling that test function right before I called ddBarChart and it alerts fine. But the call to ddBarChart has this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered a problem like this before. The problem was that the jQuery library was being included twice.

This happened in the following order:

- The HTML file loaded the jQuery file, defining the jQuery object.
- The HTML file loaded the plugin file, attaching a function to `jQuery.fn`
- The HTML file loaded the jQuery file, *redefining* the jQuery object.

After this, any references to jQuery will be on the newly defined jQuery object, which does not have the plugin function attached to it.

This would be consistent with it only failing when included from a partial view. You have to ensure the plugin is included only after the *single* jQuery source is included.

Comment: that is very interesting because my partial view is using an older version of jQuery than the "parent" view. But, the test() function in the external file works file, defined right before the ddBarChart function. I also tried changing ddBarChart to a "regular" function, defined as "function ddBarChart(options){" rather than "jQuery.fn.ddBarChart = function(options) {". But, still the same issue.

Comment: @WebDevGuy2 You are trying to have two different versions of jQuery on the same rendered page? Understand that there is only one global `jQuery` object. Most likely, when you are invoking `ddBarChart`, you are invoking it on the `newer` version, but you attached the plugin to the `older` version.

Comment: I think that might be the problem. When I do a View Source on the rendered page I see more than one reference to jQuery. You think that's it? Is it better practice to move these types of references out of partial pages and into the parent?